# Why Context list("") method returns empty collection?

Tags: java, glassfish, jndi

I want to list Glassfish JNDI tree root contents from standalone application using Context.list("") method.

JNDI tree context is initiated from the remote (127.0.0.1) Glassfish server.
Lookups work fine because I registered custom resources in "resource" context using asadmin tool.

The problem is list() returns empty collection and I get `"hasMore() returns: false"` in output.
`asadmin list-jndi-entries` (with no --context specified) gives several lines of output with
the "resource" context among them and I expected to see those lines in this sample program output.

```
package jndisampleapp;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.*;

/**
 *
 * @author user1
 */
public class JNDISampleApp {

    static Context ctx;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hashtable properties = new Hashtable(2);

        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"iiop://127.0.0.1:3700");
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");

        // Creating initial context instance.
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        // Test lookups (works fine).
        try {
            System.out.println("Res: " + String.valueOf((Double)ctx.lookup("resource/rate")));
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("Res: " + String.valueOf((Boolean)ctx.lookup("resource/flag")));
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        // Listing context contents.
        try {
            NamingEnumeration enumN = ctx.list("");
            System.out.println("hasMore() returns: " + enumN.hasMore());
            while (enumN.hasMore()) {
                NameClassPair p = (NameClassPair) enumN.next();
                System.out.println(
                        "name = " + p.getName() + ", class = " + p.getClassName());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you do `ctx.list("resource");`?

Comment: I can't try it at the moment but I have tried to list this context. I got ConnectionException in that case. If I list root context then the list() method returns empty collection and in case of specified context name it throws runtime exception.

Comment: To get the JNDI tree, surely there's a wildcard?  How do JNDI browsers get the entire tree?